# While trying to join a new peer to an existing network getting error

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I started the network using byfn.sh. Then trying to add a new peer to the network. First extended the peers after modifying crypto-config.yaml- 
Template:
      Count: 3
Then created a new yaml file with the extra peer config. Config at end.
Then from inside cli container - peer channel join -b mychannel.block

```
new peer yaml config
```

version: "2"

volumes:
  peer2.org1.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:

services:
  peer2.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer2.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: base/peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer2.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer2.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer2.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer2.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer2.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer2.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 11051:7051
      - 11053:7053

I expected- successful join. But in logs of peer2.org1 i am seeing warning- [gossip/discovery] func1 -> WARN 04e Could not connect to {peer0.org1.example.com:7051 [] [] peer0.org1.example.com:7051  } : context deadline exceeded

I have a vague idea that i need to add something for DSN discovery somewhere, but not sure where. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Add your new peer into the CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP enviroment variable of peer0.org1.example.com in the docker-compose.yaml, should be like this:

> CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.example.com:7051 peer2.org1.example.com:7051

Don't forget to restart your containers

Comment: How do i set this env var while the network is running? I bashed inside peer0 and updated the env var as follows- export CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP='peer1.org1.example.com:7051 peer2.org1.example.com:7051'. But as soon as is bash out and bash back in it is reset to earlier value.

Comment: I think you cant, you should restart your peer node to read again all env variables

Comment: While restarting can we specify a new env var to pick up? Because i stopped and removed the peer0 container and again tried to bring up only peer0 using a new yaml with new env var and got error in logs.

Comment: Maybe you had written bad the environment variable. Just separate with space every string without using quotations marks. If not this, can you paste the error logs?

Comment: 1) Used byfn.sh to bring network up (2) Edited crypto.yaml TemplateCOunt-3 (3) cryptogen extend (4) docker stop <peer0 container id>, docker rm <peer0 container> (5)docker-compose updatedpeer0.yaml- having - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.example.com:7051 peer2.org1.example.com:7051 (6) `[main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp: could not load a valid signer certificate from directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/signcerts: stat /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/signcerts: no such file or directory`

Comment: Did you added the volume msp path on the peer2?
- ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer2.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp

Comment: added as follows new-peer.yaml: - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer2.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp

Comment: Found it. Missing network var in the config present in the question. Hope it will help someone in the future.